# Pass NSWindow from Apple script to Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript

In my Cocoa app, I need to refer to another window. After searching about it a bit, it looks like that I need to use Apple scripts to do that. My question is that can I return the window of another app as a NSWindow from the Apple script to my Mac app. I've seen some Apple script samples, but not sure how to pass a value from the Apple script to the Cocoa app.
(We have a Mac touchscreen bought recently and there, in order for the touches to get detected in my unity app (through the SDK given for the Touch screen), I need to get that Unity Window and pass it to the touchscreen methods. I'm totally new to Mac development, so I can't figure out how I can pass another Window as a NSWindow to the touchscreen SDK)